# How to specify the path of kernel?

Tags: wolfram-client

I have installed Mathematica in Windows and wolframclient is installed in WSL, Windows Subsystem for Linux.
When I run WolframLanguage Session, the interpreter isn't able to locate the kernel path.

```
"Cannot locate a kernel automatically. Please provide an explicit kernel path."
wolframclient.exception.WolframKernelException: Cannot locate a kernel automatically.
Please provide an explicit kernel path.
```

The documentation available here shows how to set the path.
For instance, on linux

```
session = WolframLanguageSession('/usr/local/Wolfram/Desktop/11.3/Executables/WolframKernel')
```

Since I haven't installed Mathematica in WSL, I am not sure how to specify the path.

Any suggestions will be really helpful

Comment: On WSL your windows `C:` drive is typically accessed from `/mnt/c/`. You should consider installing `wslpath` too which helps with translation of windows style paths to Unix style.

Comment: On my machine on WSL I do `session = WolframLanguageSession('/mnt/c/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/12.1/WolframKernel.exe')`. The kernel pops up in Windows and displays a message: `Get::noopen: Cannot open /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/wolframclient/evaluation/kernel/initkernel.m`. In other words, WSL is tricking the Windows Mathematica kernel into thinking it's on linux and looking for initkernel.m in the Linux path instead of Windows. The Windows one cannot access the path. I don't think you can drive Windows Mathematica kernels from WSL using the client library.

Comment: @flinty So I guess the only option is to install Mathematica in WSL